# What do double bars around sets denote?

Tags: notation, machine-learning, neural-networks

I have never seen "magnitude bars of vectors" around a set and I also can't find anything on this use of double bars when searching for it. 
The expression this occurs in is one to "minimize the regularized, slack-rescaled, latent-variable loss" of a neural net:

$$L(\Theta) = \sum_{n=1}^N \max_{\hat{y} \in \mathcal{Y(x_n)}}\Delta(x_n, \hat{y})(1 + s(x_n, \hat{y}) - s(x_n, y_n^l)) + \lambda ||\Theta||_1$$

where $\Theta$ is a set of weight matrices and bias vectors: $\Theta = \{W, u, v, W_a, W_p, b_a, b_b\}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ is a set of predicted labels for $x_n$ and $y_n^l$ is the correct prediction and $s(a, b)$ is the prediction function of the neural net itself and $\Delta$ is a mistake-specific (whatever that means) cost function.

Does anybody know what is meant by double bars around $\Theta$ here? If it is meant to denote the cardinality of $\Theta$ then the subscript 1 makes no sense either...

(This occurs in [Learning Anaphoricity and Antecedent Ranking Features for Coreference Resolution](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~srush/acl15.pdf) on page 4.)

Comment: Perhaps the sum of the $L^1$ norms of the elements of the set.

Comment: This almost certainly means "treat $\Theta$ as a single vector and take its 1-norm". For example, if $\Theta=\{\begin{bmatrix}w_{11}&w_{12}\\w_{21}&w_{22}\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\end{bmatrix}\}$, then $\|\Theta\|_1$ probably means $\|[w_{11},w_{12},w_{21},w_{22},u_1,u_2]\|_1$, which is $|w_{11}|+|w_{12}|+|w_{21}|+|w_{22}|+|u_1|+|u_2|$.

Comment: @Rahul Ah I see, that seems to make sense and would fit the attribute "regularized". Thanks!